# Как округлять числа в языке С до целых в заданную сторону?

Tags: c

Как округлять действительные числа в языке С до ближайших целых, если нужно: 
1) Округлить до ближайшего целого числа в любую сторону
2) Округлить до ближайшего целого числа в меньшую сторону
3) Округлить до ближайшего целого числа в большую сторону
Тип данных double
Вопрос решён, спасибо

Comment: Э...  `floor()`, `ceil()`, `ronud()` чем не устроили?

Comment: Если решён, пометьте правильный ответ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вам помогут

- функция `ceil` - округление вверх
- функция `floor`- округление вниз
- функция `rint` - округляет к ближайшему целому (при default rounding mode)
- преобразование типа к целому - отбрасывание дробной части

Comment: *Отбрасывание дробной части* не равно *Округлить до ближайшего целого*.

Comment: @PinkTux согласен. уточнил ответ - добавил rint. спасибо.